# Same word with opposite meanings

Tags: etymology

The connotation of adjective 'appropriate' is positive, while that of the verb is negative.

1. What's this phenomenon called, though this question allows any part of speech (and not just an adjective and verb, as above)? I ask this so that I can try to find lists of such words.

2. Why? Does the etymology depend on each word, or is there a more general theory?

Comment: Wiktionary refers to them as *[contranyms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_contranyms)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer part 2, the etymology of *appropriate* is:

> from late Latin *appropriatus*, past participle of *appropriare* ‘make one's own,’ from *ad-* ‘to’ + *proprius* ‘own, proper.’

So it comes from a root that means both *own* and *proper*. The verb that means to take comes from the first sense (other words that are obviously related are *proprietary* and *proprietor*); the adjective that means suitable comes from the second sense.

Note that the verb isn't always negative. Another sense is:

> devote (money or assets) to a special purpose : *there can be problems in appropriating funds for legal expenses.*